# How can use internal css style in a tcpdf generated report for some table rows?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using tcpdf library to create pdf report from php and i have many tables to write on pdf report.

I want to use a css style upon some of table rows but internal css not working on it, that's why I am force to use inline style but it is so much time taking.

So anyone please give some trick if I can use internal css style script to use for all required table rows once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code for library:

```
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
```

and set the following parameters for object definition

```
  // create new PDF document
  $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

It will work.

For detail description for tcpdf library you can refer URL:
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

**All the Best**